# From a list of li, how do I tell which one is active using jquery?

Tags: jquery

From a list of li, how do I tell which one is active with a highlight class using jquery?

For example, I have the ul list

```
    <ul>
        <li> 11111111 </li>
        <li> 22222222 </li>
        <li> 33333333 </li>
        <li> 44444444 </li> <---- highlighed white/black by (.highlight) class
        <li> 55555555 </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please define "active"? Does this active li has the class "highlight" or do you want it added? Is it active on mouseover or on a certain page?

Comment: you means you want to add `highlight` class to 44444 or want to tell the browser that which `li` with value 4444 having `highlight` class??. whom u want to tell????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the selector would be:

```
$('li.highlight')
```

or if you loop through the LIs and want to check if it's active you can use .is()

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).is('.highlight')){

    }
});
```

Comment: that is what I'm looking. to see if it is active with the highlight class, thanks.

Comment: this is not working, why?  var isHighlighted = $('#ul_b li').each(function(){ if($(this).is('.highlight')){ }});alert(isHighlighted);

Comment: what do you want to do with the highlighted LIs exactly? .each() returns the whole set it was called with. ($('#ul_b li') in your case). if you just want the highlighted LIs, the selector would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li:contains(44444444)').addClass('highlight')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("li.highlight")
```

will select the active element

Comment: Thanks Nim for understanding my question.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('highlight')){

    }
});
```

Comment: `hasClass('highlight')` without the `.` ;)